# Haskell solution to Day 2 problem of Advent of Code '21

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

I won't restate the problem in full, but in a nutshell you have to parse a file with a "direction" and a "magnitude", for instance:

```
forward 8
forward 3
down 8
down 2
up 1
```

`forward` affects your horizontal position and `up` and `down` your vertical position. There are no other directions.
At the end, you're asked to multiply your final coordinates.

And this is my solution. It finds the right solution, but can it be improved?
Anything that screams "not idiomatic Haskell"?
I'm not fond of the `toTuple` function... but I had no idea how to do parse them better.

```
data Direction = Up | Down | Forward
                                                                                                           
instance Show Direction where                                                                              
    show Up = "up"                                                                                      
    show Down = "down"                                                                                  
    show Forward = "forward"                                                                          
                                                                                                      
instance Read Direction where                                                                           
    readsPrec _ "up" = [(Up, "")]                                                                          
    readsPrec _ "down" = [(Down, "")]                                                                      
    readsPrec _ "forward" = [(Forward, "")]                                                                
                                                                                                           
type HorizontalPosition = Int                                                                              
type VerticalPosition = Int                                                                           
                                                                                                           
data Position = Position {                                                                                 
    hPos :: HorizontalPosition,                                                                         
    vPos :: VerticalPosition }                                                                             
    deriving Show                                                                                       
    
move :: Position -> Direction -> Int -> Position    
move p Up n      = Position (hPos p) (vPos p - n)    
move p Down n    = Position (hPos p) (vPos p + n)                                                     
move p Forward n = Position (hPos p + n) (vPos p)                                                          
                                                                                                        
toTuple :: [String] -> (Direction, Int)                                                               
toTuple [d, n] = (read d :: Direction, read n :: Int)                                                   
                                                                                                        
main = do                                                                                               
    content <- readFile "input02"                                                                       
    let moves = map (toTuple . words) $ lines content                                                      
        position = foldl (\p (d, n) -> move p d n) (Position 0 0) moves                                                                                                                       
    putStrLn $ show $ hPos position * vPos position
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The general preference is for `Show`/`Read` instances that produce and parse (text that looks like) Haskell code. The expectation is that you should be able to paste the result of `show x` into code and get the same value out. That's to say: I don't like how you define a "weird" `Read Direction` instance. Also note that it "requires" you to define a compatible `Show`, which simply isn't contributing to solving the problem. Just define a freestanding parser.

  ```
  readDirection :: String -> Maybe Direction
  readDirection "up"      = Just Up
  readDirection "down"    = Just Down
  readDirection "forward" = Just Forward
  readDirection _         = Nothing
  ```
- Using two different `type` aliases for the components of `Position` is pointless, since they are constrained to be the same by `move`, and you're also forced to have "bare" `Int` in `move` and `direction`. If you want an alias, make one that can be used in all the parts that are "connected" (so that a change to the alias doesn't immediately break the program.)

  ```
  type Coordinate = Int
  -- see note about foldl later; using foldl' does almost nothing for a record unless it has strict fields
  data Position = Position { hPos :: !Coordinate, vPos :: !Coordinate }
  ```
- You may as well define

  ```
  data Command = Command { commandDirection :: Direction, commandDistance :: Coordinate }
  move :: Command -> Position -> Position -- writing it this way allows thinking of move :: Command -> (Position -> Position)
  move (Command Up      n) p = p { vPos = vPos p - n } -- record update syntax is a thing!
  move (Command Down    n) p = p { vPos = vPos p + n }
  move (Command Forward n) p = p { hPos = hPos p + n }
  ```

  instead of using a tuple/two separate arguments. (This also removes the need to clumsily adapt between those two representations.)
- You can now use the monadic/applicative nature of `Maybe` to define a `parseLine` nicely, instead of `toTuple`. Note that we should avoid runtime errors on invalid input (so no partial patterns allowed and no `read` allowed).

  ```
  parseLine :: String -> Maybe Command
  parseLine line = do
    [dir, n] <- return $ words line -- partial match left of <- in Maybe simply short circuits to Nothing instead of erroring
    Command <$> readDirection dir <*> readMaybe n -- read as "'Command (readDirection dir) (readMaybe n)' but with something funky going on"; in this case "something funky" is "maybe failing over to Nothing"
  ```
- I would recommend just taking input from stdin instead of hardcoding a filename. At least on reasonable shells (so not Windows...) you can write something like `./executable < input02` to connect stdin to the file `input02`.
- Now we can write `main`

  ```
  -- I like having something like this
  orDie :: String -> Maybe a -> IO a
  orDie msg Nothing = hPutStrLn stderr msg >> exitFailure
  orDie msg (Just x) = return x

  main :: IO ()
  main = do
    input <- orDie "failed to parse" =<< (traverse parseLine <$> lines <$> getContents)
    -- foldl is almost always wrong; it should be either foldr (the idiomatic one) or foldl' (the performant one)
    let finalPos = foldl' (flip move) (Position 0 0) input -- even though we have to flip move, I consider it more idiomatic to have move the way it is and chalk this flip up to "foldl is annoying"
    print $ hPos finalPos * vPos finalPos -- print = putStrLn . show
  ```

The collected imports:

```
import Text.Read(readMaybe)
import System.Exit(exitFailure)
import Data.List(foldl')
import System.IO(hPutStrLn, stderr)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review it! It didn't even occur to me I could just simply define a function `String -> Direction` to read the values and parse them instead of tinkering with the `Read` interface. Also, I must admit I still have to wrap my mind around applicatives (`<$> <*>`), which is probably why I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel every time I approach a problem. Awesome feedback and explanation, thank you!